# Java Update & Refresh BufferedImage on JPanel dynamically

Tags: java

Very new here. Trying to learn Java.

I figured I'd write a very simple "Game Of Life" auto-algorithm to see if I could grasp some of the basics - (The syntax and concepts are pretty straightforward from other languages etc.)

I've managed to muddle through and seem to be "getting the hang of it" but I've reached a pretty steep hill now.

The code described here will compile and is executable, but as you will see, despite the @override to DrawComponent and the repaint() call, the actual image displayed on-screen does not appear to change...

DIRECT QUESTION IS:
How can I ensure the display is updated every "loop"?

FLUFF & SAMPLE SOURCE:
I appreciate the procedural and non-distributed // rigid single encapsulated class here is not the ideal approach for Java, nor is this "game of life" a particularly appropriate use fothe language - BUT Iwanted to focus on getting core elements and understanding first before I 'advance' onto other things. Secondly, I appreciate this is not a very efficient solution either, but again, I wanted to learn by trying something straightforward and readable so I could easily SEE what was happening and ensure it was working properly as expected.
Third, my naming or formatting conventions may be unusual or non-standard, for this I apologise and again appreciate there are preferred ways. This was not necessarily a priority for me in learning how the language works at this time.

I welcome any advice and tips but please consider I am a complete newcomer to using Java so may not be familiar with concepts and terminologies etc.

---

```
/*                                  
Project.java                                    
By: PJ Chowdhury                                    

Entire program encapsulated in single class                                 

Created 29-Oct-2018                                 
Updated: 07-Nov-2018                                    
    Added graphics library                              
*/                                  

//Import the basic required graphics classes.                                   
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;                                    
import java.awt.*;                                  

//Import the basic applet classes.                                  
import javax.swing.*;                                   


//Core class                                    
public class project                                    
    {                               
        //Control value - determines when overpopualted or extinct                          
        private static int supercount;                          

        //Control value - how many surrounding cells must be alive for the central cell to survive                          
        private static byte thrive=4;                           

        //Define & declare effective constant size values                           
        private static byte size=64;                            
        private static byte cellsize=4;                         

        //Declare effective singleton arrays of cells                           
        private static boolean[][] cells;                           
        private static boolean[][] prolif;                          

        //Declare Window Frame                          
        public static JFrame frame;                         

        //Declare Graphics                          
        public static JPanel panel;                         

        //main entry-point. Execution must include parameter argument.                          
        public static void main(String[] args)                          
            {                       
                initialise();                   
                do                  
                    {               
                        runtime();          
                        defaultcells();         
                    }               
                while (1>0); //Bad form of course. I wanted an infinite loop. The window can be closed at user request.                 
            }                       

        //Initialises window & graphics frame                           
        public static void initialiseframe()                            
            {                       
                //Create Window                 
                frame = new JFrame("Life Cells");                   

                //Define window parameters                  
                frame.setSize((int)cellsize*size,(int)cellsize*size);                   
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                   
                frame.setVisible(true);                 

                //Create a window panel to accept graphics                  
                panel = new JPanel()                    
                    {               
                        //Overload PaintComponent method to redraw image when the frame panel is redrawn            
                        @Override           
                        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)          
                            {       
                                super.paintComponent(g);    
                            }       
                        };                  

                //attach this panel as a gadget to the frame window                 
                    frame.add(panel);                       

                //frame.pack();// Deprecated as this resizes frame window to a minimal size                 

                frame.validate(); // required since panel was added after setVisible was called                 
                frame.repaint(); // required since panel was added after setVisible was called                  
            }                       

        //Initialises & defaults cells                          
        public static void initialisecells()                            
            {                       
                //Define array sizes                    
                cells = new boolean[size][size];                    
                prolif = new boolean[size][size];                   
                // Populate with defaults                   
                defaultcells();                 
            }                       

        //Sets randomised state for each cell                           
        public static void defaultcells()                           
            {                       
                byte x;                 
                byte y;                 

                for (y=0;y<size;y++)                    
                    {               

                        for (x=0;x<size;x++)            
                            {       
                                if (Math.random()>=0.5) 
                                    {

                                    }
                                else    
                                    {

                                    }
                            }       
                    }               
            }                       

        //Wraps initialisation routines                         
        public static void initialise()                         
            {                       
                initialiseframe();                  
                initialisecells();                  
            }                       

        //iterates cells (twice) to determine if they survive or decline and draw to image                          
        public static void process()                            
            {                       
                //Prepare image for cell drawing                    
                Graphics g=panel.getGraphics();                 

                byte x;                 
                byte y;                 

                supercount=0;                   

                //First pass - check if cell will thrive                    
                for (y=0;y<size;y++)                    
                    {               

                        for (x=0;x<size;x++)            
                            {       
                                checkcell(x,y); 
                            }       
                    }               


                //Second pass - apply thrive or wither                  
                for (y=0;y<size;y++)                    
                    {               

                        for (x=0;x<size;x++)            
                            {       
                                if (updatecell(x,y))    
                                    {

                                    }
                                if (cells[x][y])    
                                    {

                                    }
                            }       
                    }               
            }                       

        //sets prolif equivalent depending on status of surrounding cells. This is used in update to set these cells to thrive                          
        public static void checkcell(byte x, byte y)                            
            {                       
                byte count=getsurrounding((int)x,(int)y);                   
                if (count>thrive)                   
                    {               
                        prolif[x][y]=true;          
                    }               
                else                    
                    {               
                        if (count<thrive)           
                            {       
                                prolif[x][y]=false; 
                            }       
                        else            
                            {       
                                prolif[x][y]=cells[x][y];   
                            }       
                    }               
            }                       

        //updates cell with prolif equivalent and returns true if cahnged                           
        public static boolean updatecell(byte x, byte y)                            
            {                       
                if (cells[x][y]!=prolif[x][y])                  
                    {               
                        cells[x][y]=prolif[x][y];           
                        return true;            
                    }               
                return false;                   
            }                       

        //returns number of thriving "cells" surrounding cell at given coords                           
        public static byte getsurrounding(int x, int y)                         
            {                       
                int u=(x-1);                    
                int v=(y-1);                    

                int ux;                 
                int vy;                 

                byte count=0;                   

                for (v=(y-1);v<(y+2);v++)                   
                    {               
                        //Use wraparound for edge cells         
                        vy=(v+size) % size;         

                        for (u=(x-1);u<(x+2);u++)           
                            {       
                                //Use wraparound for edge cells 
                                ux=(u+size) % size; 

                                //Only for surrounding cells, not this cell 
                                if ((ux!=x) & (vy!=y))  
                                    {




                                    }

                            }       
                    }               
                return count;                   
            }                       

        //Draw cell at x,y : not the most efficient nor elegant method...                           
        public static void drawcell(Graphics g, int x, int y, boolean live)                         
            {                       
                if (live)                   
                    {               
                        // Draw this cell alive         
                        //g.setColor(Color.GREEN);          
                    }               
                else                    
                    {               
                        // Draw this cell dead          
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);            
                    }               

                g.fillRect(x*cellsize, y*cellsize,cellsize,cellsize);                   

                panel.repaint(x*cellsize, y*cellsize,cellsize,cellsize);                    
            }                       

        //Returns true if population is healthy. False if extinct or overcrowded                            
        public static boolean populationanalysis()                          
            {                       
                        return ((supercount<thrive)||(supercount>(int)(size*size)<<1));         
            }                       

        //Main Loop method                          
        public static void runtime()                            
            {                       
                int sanity=5000;                    
                int loopcount=0;                    
                do                  
                    {               
                        process();          
                        loopcount++;            
                        if (populationanalysis())           
                            {       
                                break;  
                            }       
                    }               
                while (loopcount<sanity);                   
            }                       
    }
```

Comment: I am confident that frame.repaint() cascades to a re-paint of panel too (?)
At least, calling panel.repaint() in the runtime loop did not seem to show any visible difference.

I'm leaning towards thinking that I am confusing graphics objects somewhere - for example drawing updates to the panel, then overwiting this with the initial image?

Getting warmer?

Comment: Removed the BufferedImage entirely and now draw straight to Panel (source above now updated to reflect this)
The lack of BufferedImage possibly invalidates the question. However, there are still issues but I think these may be more logic/syntax related.